# How to get constant hashcode (Uint32 or Int32) for a string but being outside of a range

Tags: c#, associations, hashcode, .net-7.0, crc32

According to this [article](https://andrewlock.net/why-is-string-gethashcode-different-each-time-i-run-my-program-in-net-core/) the official "GetHashCode" for a string is made randomly per execution to prevent Hacking. But I need to persist the hashcode so I want it to be always the same per specific string.

In the same article I saw a way to get an HashCode but I wonder if there is better solution and/or if there is a way to direcly get a Hash code outside of a specific range (like 0 - 2000)? Any Uint32 ouside of [0-2000].

Comment: The documentation you linked to doesn't show a `ComputeCrc32` method, only `Hash`, `TryHash`, `Append`, and `Reset`, and I was [unable to reproduce the issue](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zs13WN) when calling `Crc32.Hash`, i.e it found the namespace in the `using` directive and was able to use the `Crc32` class from it.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858947/c-sharp-fast-crc32-calculation. If you want to do it yourself, it's easy to test since it's a standard algorithm and there are online calculators

Comment: see the code that I posted, that worked, for CRC32c poly = 0x82f63b78u and for CRC32 poly = 0xedb88320u

Comment: Look at //FOR NO SPECIFIC OS// part in Crc32C.cs. Don't forget use poly = 0xedb88320u for CRC32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Crc32C.ARM.cs**

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.Arm;

namespace DiscountCard.Ext.Mod.CRC32
{
    partial class Crc32C
    {
        public static class ImplARM
        {
            public static uint Update(uint crc, ReadOnlySpan<byte> input)
            {
                crc ^= uint.MaxValue;
                while (input.Length >= 4)
                {
                    crc = Crc32.ComputeCrc32C(crc, Unsafe.ReadUnaligned<uint>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(input)));
                    input = input.Slice(sizeof(uint));
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
                {
                    crc = Crc32.ComputeCrc32C(crc, input[i]);
                }
                return crc ^ uint.MaxValue;
            }

            public static uint Update64(uint crc, ReadOnlySpan<byte> input)
            {
                crc ^= uint.MaxValue;
                while (input.Length >= sizeof(ulong))
                {
                    crc = Crc32.Arm64.ComputeCrc32C(crc, Unsafe.ReadUnaligned<ulong>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(input)));
                    input = input.Slice(sizeof(ulong));
                }
                if (input.Length >= 4)
                {
                    crc = Crc32.ComputeCrc32C(crc, Unsafe.ReadUnaligned<uint>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(input)));
                    input = input.Slice(sizeof(uint));
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
                {
                    crc = Crc32.ComputeCrc32C(crc, input[i]);
                }
                return crc ^ uint.MaxValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Crc32C.X86.cs**

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86;

namespace DiscountCard.Ext.Mod.CRC32
{
    partial class Crc32C
    {
        public static class ImplX86
        {
            public static uint Update(uint crc, ReadOnlySpan<byte> input)
            {
                crc ^= uint.MaxValue;
                while (input.Length >= sizeof(uint))
                {
                    crc = Sse42.Crc32(crc, Unsafe.ReadUnaligned<uint>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(input)));
                    input = input.Slice(sizeof(uint));
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
                {
                    crc = Sse42.Crc32(crc, (byte)input[i]);
                }
                return crc ^ uint.MaxValue;
            }

            public static uint Update64(uint crc, ReadOnlySpan<byte> input)
            {
                ulong crcl = crc ^ uint.MaxValue;
                while (input.Length >= sizeof(ulong))
                {
                    crcl = Sse42.X64.Crc32(crcl, Unsafe.ReadUnaligned<ulong>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(input)));
                    input = input.Slice(sizeof(ulong));
                }
                crc = unchecked((uint)crcl);
                if (input.Length >= 4)
                {
                    crc = Sse42.Crc32(crc, Unsafe.ReadUnaligned<uint>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(input)));
                    input = input.Slice(sizeof(uint));
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
                {
                    crc = Sse42.Crc32(crc, (byte)input[i]);
                }
                return crc ^ uint.MaxValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Crc32C.cs**

```
#define X86_INTRINSICS

using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

#if X86_INTRINSICS
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86;
#endif
#if ARM_INTRINSICS
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.Arm;
#endif

namespace DiscountCard.Ext.Mod.CRC32
{
    public static unsafe partial class Crc32C
    {

        private static uint* table;
        private const uint poly = 0x82f63b78u;
        private static delegate*<uint, ReadOnlySpan<byte>, uint> ptr;
        static Crc32C()
        {
#if X86_INTRINSICS
            if (Sse42.X64.IsSupported)
            {
                ptr = &ImplX86.Update64;
                goto end_decision;
            }
            if (Sse42.IsSupported)
            {
                ptr = &ImplX86.Update;
                goto end_decision;
            }
#endif
#if ARM_INTRINSICS
            if (Crc32.Arm64.IsSupported)
            {
                ptr = &ImplARM.Update64;
                goto end_decision;
            }
            if (Crc32.IsSupported)
            {
                ptr = &ImplARM.Update;
                goto end_decision;
            }
#endif
            // FOR NO SPECIFIC OS ///////////
            InitializeTable();
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            {
                ptr = &UpdateLittleEndianOptimized;
                goto end_decision;
            }
            ptr = &UpdateNative;
            // END OF FOR NO SPECIFIC OS ///

        end_decision:;
        }

        static void InitializeTable()
        {
            table = (uint*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(16 * 256 * 4);
            for (uint i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                uint res = i;
                for (int t = 0; t < 16; t++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) res = (res & 1) == 1 ? poly ^ (res >> 1) : (res >> 1);
                    table[(t * 256) + i] = res;
                }
            }
        }

        static uint UpdateLittleEndianOptimized(uint crci, ReadOnlySpan<byte> input)
        {
            // Copyright (C) 2013 Mark Adler
            ulong crc;

            crc = crci ^ 0xffffffff;
            while (input.Length >= sizeof(ulong))
            {
                crc ^= Unsafe.ReadUnaligned<ulong>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(input));
                crc = table[(7 * 256) + (crc & 0xff)] ^
                      table[(6 * 256) + ((crc >> 8) & 0xff)] ^
                      table[(5 * 256) + ((crc >> 16) & 0xff)] ^
                      table[(4 * 256) + ((crc >> 24) & 0xff)] ^
                      table[(3 * 256) + ((crc >> 32) & 0xff)] ^
                      table[(2 * 256) + ((crc >> 40) & 0xff)] ^
                      table[(1 * 256) + ((crc >> 48) & 0xff)] ^
                      table[(0 * 256) + (crc >> 56)];
                input = input.Slice(sizeof(ulong));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                crc = table[(0 * 256) + ((crc ^ input[i]) & 0xff)] ^ (crc >> 8);
            }
            return (uint)crc ^ 0xffffffff;
        }

        static uint UpdateNative(uint crc, ReadOnlySpan<byte> input)
        {
            crc ^= uint.MaxValue;
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                crc = table[(0 * 256) + ((crc ^ input[i]) & 0xff)] ^ (crc >> 8);
            }
            return crc ^ uint.MaxValue;
        }


        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static uint Update(uint crc, ReadOnlySpan<byte> input) => ptr(crc, input);

    }
}
```

**HOW TO USE?**

**A. For CRC32C**

```
uint result = Crc32C.Update(0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("There is no God but Allah"));
MessageBox.Show(result.ToString("X")); // result: C16698CA
```

**B. For CRC32**

Change **poly** from

```
private const uint poly = 0x82f63b78u;
```

To

```
private const uint poly = 0xedb88320u;



uint result = Crc32C.Update(0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("There is no God but Allah"));
MessageBox.Show(result.ToString("X")); // result: 0xFABB17B6
```

Comment: There is many errors in my question. I will re-asked more appropriately. In order to thank you for your answer, I will mark it as the right one. Thanks.

Comment: But I will delete it because I dont, think it could help anybody it its actual form. I have errors in code also.

Comment: I tried to delete it but I got a big warning, so I modified it to better fit my need.